# Ruby: using `.each` or `.step`, step forward a random amount for each iteration

Tags: ruby, random, iterator

*(Also open to other similar non-Rails methods)*

Given `(0..99)`, return entries that are randomly picked in-order.

Example results:

`0, 5, 11, 13, 34..`

`3, 12, 45, 67, 87`

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5..` (very unlikely, of course)

Current thought:

```
(0..99).step(rand(0..99)).each do |subindex|
  array.push(subindex)
end
```

However, this sets a single random value for all the steps whereas I'm looking for each step to be random.

Comment: Doesn't `(0..99).step(rand(0..99)).to_a` work for you?. `(0..99)` gives you a "sorted" range, and the step is "random", so the length of the result is "uncertain".

Comment: Is the process as follows? Randomly pick a number between `0` and `99`. Suppose that number is `31`. Next pick a random number between `32` (or would that be `31`?) and `99`. Suppose that is `72`. Then pick a number between `73` (or `72`?) and `99`. Continue until `99` has been picked, then quit. Why do you wish to do that?

Comment: The process you have in mind would result in a heavily biased distribution. If you increment randomly on each step, you're much more likely to get higher numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a random value for the number of elements to pick, randomly get this number of elements, sort.

```
(0..99).to_a.sample((0..99).to_a.sample).sort
#⇒ [7, 20, 22, 29, 45, 48, 57, 61, 62, 76, 80, 82]
```

Or, shorter (credits to @Stefan):

```
(0..99).to_a.sample(rand(0..99)).sort
#⇒ [7, 20, 22, 29, 45, 48, 57, 61, 62, 76, 80, 82]
```

Or, in more functional manner:

```
λ = (0..99).to_a.method(:sample)
λ.(λ.()).sort
```

To feed exactly `N` numbers:

```
N = 10
(0..99).to_a.sample(N).sort
#⇒ [1, 5, 8, 12, 45, 54, 60, 65, 71, 91]
```

Comment: `(0..99).to_a.sample` → `rand(0..99)`

Comment: `λ.(λ.()).sort` I love that :-)

Comment: @Stefan I started to type “I wonder how would you beautify `λ.(λ.()).sort` then?” :) It’s cute, yes and looks so fashionable.

Comment: @Stefan since we are going for brevity `rand(0..99)` → `rand(100)`

Comment: @engineersmnky the question says _"Given (0..99)"_, so I wanted to keep that, but yeah, that's another option.

Answer (score 2):

There're many ways to achieve it.

For example here's slow yet simple one:

```
# given `array`
random_indexes = (0...array.size).to_a.sample(rand(array.size))
random_indexes.sort.each { |i| puts array[i] }
```

Or why don't you just:

```
array.each do |value|
  next if rand(2).zero?
  puts value
end
```

Or you could use `Enumerator#next` random number of times.

Comment: @mudasobwa 1) "here's slow yet simple one:", 2) "or ...", 3) "or ...".

Answer (score 2):

Below example returns a sorted array with random entries from given range based on randomly picked `true` or `false` from array `[true, false]`:

```
(0..99).select { [true, false].sample }
 => [0, 3, 12, 13, 14, 17, 20, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 65, 67, 69, 70, 71, 79, 81, 84, 86, 91, 93, 94, 95, 98, 99]
```

To reduce the chances of a bigger array being returned, you can modify your `true/false` array to include more falsey values:

```
(0..99).select { ([true] + [false] * 9).sample }
 => [21, 22, 28, 33, 37, 58, 59, 63, 77, 85, 86]
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'd use `rand < 0.5` or `rand < 0.1` to adjust the probability, though.